# asp.net insert a specific image into database from code behind

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, image

I would like to insert a specific image into the database when a specific value is selected in a dropdownlist. I would to use a switch statement to insert different image depending on the value selected.

here is my code so far:

```
  protected void ButtonSkicka_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Conn.Open();
            SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into NorrgårdsvägenKomm (Namn, Kommentar, DateTime, Tag) values (@Namn, @Kommentar, @DateTime, @Tag)", Conn);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Namn", TextBoxNamn.Text);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kommentar", TextBoxMedd.Text);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", System.DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tag", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Conn.Close();

            string Value;
            Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;

            switch (Value)
            {
                case "Högprio":
                    Conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand Cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into NorrgårdsvägenKomm (VarningsBild) values (@VarningsBild)", Conn);
                    Cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VarningsBild", "Images/Högprio.png/");
                    Cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Conn.Close();
                    break;
            }

            TextBoxNamn.Text = "";
            TextBoxMedd.Text = "";

            Response.Redirect("Norrgårdsvägen.aspx");



        }

        catch (Exception ex)
```

I just don't know how to insert the right image just from the code? Thanks!

Comment: are you going to save image or image path? it seems like you are saving the path only. what is the field type in your database?

Comment: @un-lucky I want to use an image that already exits in a folder and just insert that one to the column. The column is just nvarchar

Comment: You need to convert the image to bytes store in a column with binary(8000) type. 8000 is max and 1 is min.

Comment: @Oluwafemi It works just fine storing images as a string. I just don't know how to insert via the code provided above